# Создание проекта с несколькими классами Java

Tags: java, классы, наследование

Есть задание: создать класс и его наследника. Создавать классы стоит в одном файле java или каждый должен быть в своем файле с расширением `.java`?

Comment: Зависит от задачи.

Comment: К примеру человек, студент-наследующий первого

Comment: Я имел в виду от обширности задачи. Если в последствие планируются еще наследники, если классы не маленькие, разрастаться функционалом планируется и т.д. - то конечно разные классы..... А если, грубо говоря, нужно лишь сделать задачу по наследованию, чтоб понять урок, с небольшим набором полей - то смысла особо нет. Так в вашем случае, можно наверное обойтись и одним файлом....А в целом классы разделяют по файлам

Comment: Надо учитывать, что имя `public` класса верхнего уровня должно совпадать с именем файла, поэтому такой класс в файле будет только один. Это единственное реальное ограничение. Мелкие задачки, чтоб не плодить проекты и не засорять в одном проекте пространство имен, можете заводить под каждый урок отдельный под-пакет, или использовать вложенные статические классы в классе с `main`.

Comment: спасибо,буду иметь ввиду

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем случае лучше создать в одном файле оба класса, однако всегда лучше создавать каждый класс в отдельном файле

Comment: а проеэкт создавать с главным классом "человек"? и объясните, пожалуйста, еще почему обычно создают в разных файлах

Comment: Как правило главный класс `Main` с точкой входа `public static void main(String[] args)`

Comment: то есть классы "человек", "студент", "main"(в нем не будет никаких полей и методов кроме главного, а в нем происходят "основные действия"-создание экземпляров классов "человек" и "студент", к примеру)? правильноли я Вас понял?

Comment: .......Угу.....

Comment: сразу прошу прощения, за глупый вопрос, но решил выяснить до конца. какую роль выполняет главный класс, метод главного класса          public static void main(String[] args) нужен, чтобы существовал этот главный класс, но ведь фактически мы работаем с двумя классами, какэто для себя понять?

Comment: `main()` - основной метод. Это - строка, с которой начинается выполнение программы. Точка входа. Все приложения `Java` должны иметь один метод `main()`.  ......Класс, который не имеет основного метода, может быть успешно откомпилирован, но не может быть выполнен, поскольку он не имеет отправной точки выполнения, которой является `main()` метод

Comment: а создать метод main без класса main не можна,соответственно он нужен в любом случае, понял, спасибо

Comment: @MuscledBoy Класс с точкой входа `main()` может быть назван как угодно, хоть `class RahamBaharamamBuru`. Главное чтоб был главный класс с точкой входа. Просто зачастую этот главный класс называют `Main` (с большой буквы) .....в глаза бросается и сразу интуитивно понятно что это за класс

Comment: спасибо, вопрос исчерпан